# Using Apache Commons IO in a Gradle project

Tags: java, apache, gradle

I'm writing a Java program - a plain command line program, not Android or anything like that - using Gradle, and trying to include Apache Commons IO. Per https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.6 I ended up with `build.gradle` like this:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
}

mainClassName = 'Main'
```

Gradle seems to download the package happily enough, but import statements referring to `apache` or `commons` get a not found error; this is true even when I run `gradle build` from the command line, omitting any IDE. What am I missing? (Previous similar discussions have been for Android or Eclipse projects; the instructions for those haven't worked here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problems with your Gradle script, so at first glance, I'm thinking of two possible explanations:

- you import a class that cannot be found in the artifact (e.g. a previous version of commons-io deprecated it and now they removed it)
- your project's structure is set up incorrectly

I copied the exact contents of your script in a *build.gradle* file, created a *src/main/java* directory structure in the same directory, and wrote a small application *Main.java* under that directory with the following:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOCase;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(IOCase.SENSITIVE.checkEndsWith("abcd1234", "1234"));
    }
}
```

The code compiles successfully, so I need more context to troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: Tried your test case and it worked, went back to my project and it works, so I don't know what was going wrong before, maybe something hadn't saved/updated? But it works now, thanks!